# Python Decorators Error- decorated_view() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)"

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I want to decorate the view in Django with my decorator. Basically I want to authenticate a user with an `auth-token` key to authorize its credentials, before accessing any end-point URL of the API:-

Here is my code:-

```
class XYZResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = XYZ.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'xyz'
        allowed_methods = ['get','post','delete','put']

    @roles_accepted('admin','staff')
    def obj_get(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        ..............

    @roles_accepted('admin','staff')
    def get_object_list(self, request): 
        ......


    @roles_accepted('admin','staff')
    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
         ......

    @roles_accepted('admin','staff')
    def obj_update(self, bundle, **kwargs):
             ......


    @roles_accepted('admin','staff')
    def obj_delete(self, bundle, **kwargs):
             ......
```

Here is my decorator:-

```
def roles_accepted(*roles):
    def wrapper(fn):
        def decorated_view(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
            if check_role(request) in roles  or check_role(request.request) in roles: # for POST,PUT,DELETE where bundle is passed, 
                return fn(self,request,*args, **kwargs)                               # auth_token is contained in bundle.request
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(create_json_response({"error": "Unauthorized user"}, HttpUnauthorized)) 
        return decorated_view
    return wrapper
```

The error that I'm facing is when I request `POST/GET-ALL` , it works fine , but when I perform 'GET/DELETE/PUT' request, it says:-

```
{
  "error_message": "decorated_view() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)",
  "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 195, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 435, in dispatch_detail\n    return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 458, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1408, in put_detail\n    updated_bundle = self.obj_update(bundle=bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\nTypeError: decorated_view() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)\n"
}
```

Since `POST` and `PUT/DELETE/GET` contains same parameter, then what different is happening in case of `PUT/DELETE/GET` requests?

Comment: Can we see the relevant lines where you "perform 'GET/DELETE/PUT' request" ?

Comment: Relevent line?? What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some of the functions you wrap accept an argument called `request`, and others accept an argument called `bundle`, but your decorator always calls that argument `request`.  This causes an error when Tastypie's internals try to pass a `bundle` keyword argument.  Your decorator does not know about any argument named `bundle`, so it is collected in `**kwargs` and your decorator does not receive a `request` argument.

I don't know enough about Django or Tastypie to know what the difference is supposed to be between `request` and bundle.  If they are the same thing under different names, you could roll that argument into `kwargs` and have your decorator manually look in there for an argument named either `request` or `bundle`.  If the arguments `request` and `bundle` mean different things, you may need to write two different decorators to handle them appropriately.

Comment: Since POST and PUT/DELETE/GET contains same parameter, then what different is happening in case of PUT/DELETE/GET requests? /requests are successful in case of POST but not in case of others , though all contains same parameters/

Comment: @user1162512: I don't know what you mean by "POST and PUT/DELETE/GET contains same parameter".  I don't know what methods are getting called by those requests.  But I can see in your code that one of the methods has a `request` argument and the others have `bundle`, and I can see from the traceback that Tastypie is trying to call with a `bundle` argument.  Note that just because you pass the same HTTP information to a POST/GET request doesn't mean that the same functions in your code will be called.  There's a difference between HTTP parameters and Python function arguments.